# How do you calculate this sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

I can not find the function from which I have to start to calculate this power series.
 $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$$
Any tips?.
Thanks.

Comment: [Strongly related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587333/how-to-prove-the-closed-form-left-frac-11-x-right2-sum-n-0-infty#comment1239936_587333).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333192/solve-sum-nxn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remember

$$ \sum x^n = \frac{1}{1-x } $$

for $|x| < 1 $

Comment: and then?
derive both sides?

Comment: yessssssssssssss

Comment: excellent
thanks

Answer (score 3):

We can do it another way.

$S = x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + \ldots $

It can be written as

$ \Rightarrow S = (x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots)+(x^2 + x^3 + \ldots)+(x^3 + \ldots)+\ldots $

$\Rightarrow S = (x + x^2 + x^3 + ...)+x(x + x^2 + ...)+x^2(x + ...) + \ldots $

$\Rightarrow S = ( 1+x+x^2+ .. )\times( x+x^2+.. )$

$\Rightarrow S = \frac{1}{1-x}\times\frac{x}{1-x}$

$\Rightarrow S = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} $

Comment: mmm interesting